# HTML line wrapping w/ punctuation

Tags: html, text, webkit

I have some content that uses multiple punctuation marks in a row: "...what road?, others are roads..."

WebKit likes to break this between '?' and ','

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Use well-formed punctuation. A comma *shouldn't* immediately follow a question mark.

Comment: In German it may. Goethe's Faust has a few examples, iirc.

Comment: Thanks Niko, I was thinking of English, of course. Anyway, I realise that punctuation is one of the first features of language to fall by the wayside when it must be adapted for/by an international audience. I'm just pining for the old days.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the quote comes from a novel that was written in Italian and translated into English. There's an edge case for everything!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the 'word joiner' character (U+2060, or &#8288;) to prevent a line from breaking between two characters.

Should work in any standards-compliant browser.

The zero-width-no-break-space is an alternative.